# Unable to return all values from other spreadsheet. Currently getting the first test case for each test point but need 10 test cases for each point

Tags: excel, vba, loops

```
Sub GenerateTestCase()
 
Dim Tf As Double
Dim Pf As Double
Dim Zf As Double
Dim Zb As Double
 
Dim TestCaseNumber As Integer
Dim p As Integer
Dim t As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim i As Integer
 
 
For TestCaseNumber = 0 To 7
 
    Tf = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("B3").Offset(TestCaseNumber * 2, 0).Value
    Pf = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("C3").Offset(TestCaseNumber * 2, 0).Value
  
    
Call ImplementValues(Tf, Pf)
Call ReturnValues(Zf, Zb)
   
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2").Range("E6").Offset(p * 4, 3 * TestCaseNumber).Value = Zf
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2").Range("E7").Offset(p * 4, 3 * TestCaseNumber).Value = Zb
   
Next TestCaseNumber
 
End Sub
 
Sub ImplementValues(Tf As Double, Pf As Double)
 
    For i = 0 To 9
   
        With Workbooks("XYZ).Worksheets("11")
            .Range("D54").Offset(32 * i, 0).Value = Tf
            .Range("C54").Offset(32 * i, 0).Value = Pf
           
        End With
   
    Next i
 
End Sub
 
Sub ReturnValues(Zf As Double, Zb As Double)
 
 
    For p = 0 To 9
   
        Zf = Workbooks("XYZ").Worksheets("11").Range("J54").Offset(32 * p, 0).Value
        Zb = Workbooks("XYZ").Worksheets("11").Range("T54").Offset(32 * p, 0).Value
   
        'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(" 2").Range("E6").Offset(p * 4, 0).Value = Zf
        'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2").Range("E7").Offset(p * 4, 0).Value = Zb
       
    Next p
       
End Sub
```

Comment: The code above is a generalized version of the original

Comment: your code above shouldn't even compile due to a missing " in `With Workbooks("XYZ).Worksheets("11")` ; also, use Option Explicit at the top of your code and declare all your variables. You never increment `p` in `GenerateTestCase` so you would overwrite in loop.

Comment: `p`=0 in `GenerateTestCase`

Comment: oh I think I erased that while simplifying my code, the original did have a with and it compiled aswell. Sorry im very new two programming so this may be a dumb question but Option Explicit will make it loop through p?

Comment: @QHarr I tried that but it didn't make a difference. What I need is to get 10 different Zf and Zb values for each Test Point. The Test Points are organized in columns and the test cases are in rows. Currently I'm getting only the first Zf and Zb values for each test point ( the remaining 9 rows are empty) for each test point